# Dynamic routes in SailsJs

Tags: javascript, api, routes, sails.js

I want to create a dynamic route.
I created an API named users. And I need can access to /users/:nameofuser, like an auto created users/id.

How to get a username in this type of url, and execute a controller for search for it in the DB?

I try with this code in routes.js, but it doesn't work for me:

```
'users/:name': 'UserController.getUser',

'users/all/:name': 'UserController.getUser'
```

I always receive a 404 error with this text: No record found with the specified `id`.

Comment: in apis usually its the `id` you use to call the api. You could use the [waterline query language](http://sailsjs.org/documentation/concepts/models-and-orm/query-language) to query via name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`users/:id` automatically routes to `UserController.find`. If this action is not present in your controller it uses the default blueprint action, which requires an ID parameter. To solve your problem you can simply override the find method:

```
find: function (req, res) {
    var name = req.param('id');
    User.findOne({name: name}).exec(function(err, user) {
        if (err) {return res.serverError(err);}
        return res.json(user);
    });
}
```

However if you still want to get users by ID you should create an extra route:

```
'users/:name': 'UserController.getUser',
```

and

```
getUser: function (req, res) {
    var name = req.param('name');
    User.findOne({name: name}).exec(function(err, user) {
        if (err) {return res.serverError(err);}
        return res.json(user);
    });
}
```